# how can I speed up query with 3 function calls in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `fucntion pb(IDCODE,0)`  running it with `IDCODE=320` gives this sample data:

```
select *
from pb(320,0)



logid entrydate qty
1       1.10.17   5
2       1.10.17   6
3       1.10.17   5
4       1.10.17   -3
5       2.10.17   6
6       3.10.17  -100
```

*it actually gives more rows (like 20000) but I reduced it for the example

pb is a very heavy function but in simple terms it shows activities based on their order.

I want to find the `entrydate` of the first occurrences of `qty<0` after the last row of `qty>0`.

In order to do that I need to do something like this:

```
Select Min(logid) where qty<0 and logid>(select max(logid) where qty>=0)
```

In the above sample the requested result is `3.10.17` 
Because:

`logid=5` is `max(logid) where qty>=0`

and

`logid=6` is `Min(logid) where qty<0 and logid>(select max(logid) where qty>=0)`
  which in fact is :   `Select Min(logid) where qty<0 and logid>5`

**So I wrote the following query:**

```
select entrydate
from pb(320,0)
where logid= (     SELECT min(logid)
                    FROM pb(320,0)
                    where qty<0 and logid>(SELECT coalesce(max(logid),0)
                                           FROM pb(320,0)
                                           WHERE qty >= 0))
```

**This works great but it's 3 times that I call the function `pb(320,0)`.**

It's huge time consuming and needless to say that I actually run this query on many IDCODES (like 214) so `pb(IDCODE,0)` actually runs `214*3` this is horrible.

What can I do?

Comment: if the output of the function won't change in single statement change the volatility of the function to stable and compare results

Comment: Rewrite the function into a VIEW? BTW: what is inside the function?

Comment: PostgreSQL sometimes loses a lot of performance on sub-selects. In functions you are better off assigning results into variables (like `SELECT max() INTO maxValue...`) and using the variable in a more simple query. Just my two cents.

Comment: @BorisSchegolev: for the planner there is no way to get an estimate for the number of rows resulting from the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a CTE, because Postgres might materialize the CTE.

However, you need only one table reference if you use window functions:

```
with t as (
      select *
      from pb(320,0)
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(case when qty > 0 then logid end) over () as last_poslogid
      from t
     ) t
where id > last_poslogid and qty < 0
order by id
fetch first 1 row only;
```

More recent versions of Postgres support the `filter` clause which is a bit more efficient than the `case`.